# mongodb '$exists' does not retain all the fields in my colleague's computers but retains all fields in mine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo. I have a collection call monkeys. I wanted to query all monkeys objects that have the fields 'themes' inside 'textAnalysis' field and that has owner id of 3.  I used this code:

```
all_monkeys = db.monkeys.find({"textAnalysis.themes": {"$exists": True}}, {"owner": 3})
for monkey in all_monkeys:
    print(monkey)
```

We get only '_id' and 'owner' fields printed in my colleague's computers but I get all the fields in my computer. This is weird. Any thoughts what could be causing it. I use Mac and my colleague uses Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a subtly mis-placed close brace (the joys of MongoDB!). Try this:

```
all_monkeys = db.monkeys.find({"textAnalysis.themes": {"$exists": True}, "owner": 3})
for monkey in all_monkeys:
    print(monkey)
```

Comment: many thanks. this works like magic. still don't understand why I did get all the fields while my colleague did not. Could it be operating system difference?

Comment: No, it's a difference in semantics. The first argument to the method is an object representing the query. The second is [the projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) representing the fields from the matching documents to return